# Filtering tags of featured articles Joomla within override of featured articles

Tags: module, articles, tags, content-filtering

In Joomla 3, I want to filter on tags for featured articles within an override of featured/default.php itself. 
I have a module that filters the tags of featured articles out.

Is it possible to 'use' the results of the module within the override?

And after that set a filtering on it with Javascript?

The module (position) itself can be added to default.php, but I want to go a step further.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to 'use' the results of the module within the override?

I do not think that it is possible. `featured/default.php` and module are in the same execution cycle so you can not pass module results to the request and then use it in `featured/default.php`.